# How to make the values inside the mongodb connect function global

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In the following code I just stored some data from mongodb in a variable(`data`).Now how can I make this `data` Global?

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    var data;
    mongodb.connect(url,{useNewUrlParser:true},(err,db)=>{
        var dbo=db.db('pract')
        var cursor=dbo.collection('samp').find({_id:1410})
        cursor.forEach(function(doc){
            data=doc;
        })
    }) 
    console.log(data)
    res.end()
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let data;
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    mongodb.connect(url,{useNewUrlParser:true},(err,db)=>{
        var dbo=db.db('pract')
        var cursor=dbo.collection('samp').find({_id:1410})
        cursor.forEach(function(doc){
            data=doc;
        })
    }) 
    console.log(data)
    res.end()
})
```

Comment: But the output is showing ```undefined```.I know this is a javascript asynchronous stuff.Could you please help me how can I get data value printed?